# What is the Neon equivalent of ARM's umlal instruction?

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

I have a piece of code that I attempt to optimize however I cant find the SIMD / Vector equivalent of umlal:

```
umlal  r1, r2, r3, r4
```

Such instruction exits?

Thanks!

Comment: Given that it's a multiply-accumulate operation, how closely did you look at _all_ the variants of `vmla`?

Comment: I am so so new to ARM asm, I didnt even knew where to start looking...
from further looking I think that VMLAL.U32 can do the job ... however I'm not 100% sure. anyone knows?

Comment: Here's a good list of the intrinsics and instructions they represent. The VMLAL_U32() should be turned into umlal. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html

Comment: I sympathize a lot with this question.  If google lands you in the wrong part of infocenter.arm.com, you might not find VMLAL.  Their docs are sometimes a mess, and it doesn't help you that they are continually making more stuff docs offline for paying customers.  Which is  kinda okay, because most of the ISA reference is for their assembler, and since we're using gas and not armasm, it makes sense to use the docs for the assembler we're using.  But gas docs won't get you far either.

Comment: @PeterM I won't say Infocenter isn't horrible to navigate, but for reference, most of what's on there - including the architecture reference manuals which are the go-to for canonical ISA information - is available if you sign up a free account to accept the legal agreements (which is what "registered ARM customers" turns out to actually mean). The docs which really are exclusive to _paying_ customers (i.e. licensees) only come as part of the licensed deliverables anyway.

Comment: Oh cool.  Thanks!  That is very useful. Just to highlight my point using this particular example, If you google "Neon Multiply Instructions" then you're looking at the DS-5 docs.  Google will help you land in the right-ish place, if that place is ARM Compiler toolchain Assembler Reference Version 5.01, NEON multiply instructions, then you'll see VMUL{L} and variants.  If you end up at Version 5.03 then you only see VMUL, with no curly-bracket hint that there are widening instruction variants.

Comment: The reason is that ARM decided that VMUL and VMULL were different enough that they shouldn't be on the same page, but when they split the instruction into two pages, they totally forgot to include the new VMULL page on the summary/TOC "Neon Multiply instructions" page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMLAL.U32 is probably what you are looking for.

Note that looking at the intrinsics list is sometimes a little easier if you can go by the "C" prototype and see what the data types are and stuff.  Some of the ARM NEON references seem deficient in finding variants.

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/BABDEAGJ.html

or

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html

(just saw bitbank's comment)

Comment: Thanks :) The intrinsics tip is helpfull